# How to specify number of leading zeros in int_to_bin (expl3)

Tags: expl3

How can I tell int_to_bin how many leading zeros I want?

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \displayasbinary #1 {0b\int_to_bin:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\displayasbinary{3}, but should be: 0b0011
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `\int_to_bin:n` is a 'programming' function, it doesn't do padding. WE can add that by counting up the tokens in converted output, then making enough `0` to pad:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \hk_int_to_bin:nn #1#2
   {
     \exp_args:Ne \__hk_int_to_bin:nn { \int_to_bin:n {#2} } {#1}
   }
\cs_new:Npn \__hk_int_to_bin:nn #1#2
  {
    0b
    \prg_replicate:nn { \int_max:nn { 0 } { (#2) -\tl_count:n {#1} } } { 0 }
    #1
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \displayasbinary { O{4} m }
  { \hk_int_to_bin:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\displayasbinary{3}, but should be: 0b0011 or \displayasbinary[10]{3}
or \displayasbinary[0]{3}
\end{document}
```